# Fingerprint crash on Android 11

Tags: codenameone

I follow the example code in the following document [fingetprint support](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/fingerprint-touchid-support.html) to add fingerprint support in my codenameone project.

My codenameone program crashes running on the codes

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(value -> {
    Log.p("Scan successfull!");
}, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
    Log.p("Scan Failed!");
});
```

I have installed the cn1 fingerprint extension on Netbeans IDE and run the program on Android 11.

Error dump by logcat application com.visionx.vision

```
--------- beginning of crash
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.visionx.vision, PID: 11740
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Title must be set and non-empty
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt$Builder.build(BiometricPrompt.java:561)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at c.a.l.b.f$c.run(InternalFingerprintImpl.java:10)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
03-03 15:53:00.707 11740 11740 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
03-03 15:53:00.708  6402  6455 D MobileSignalIconsSelector: getDataIconGroup(): connected=true,enabled=true,level=2,inetCondition=1,dataIconGroup=DataIconGroup(4G+),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,lastModified=03-03 15:53:00.707,dataSim=true,networkName=中華電信,networkNameData=中華電信,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,defaultDataOff=false,cdmaEriIconIndex=-1,cdmaEriIconMode=-1,callState=0,voWifiConnected=false,shouldShowDisabledDataIcon=false,bluetoothTethered=false,isLTEFemtoCell=false,cardOperator=OTHERS,optionalRadioTech=0,isCAIndicator=true,isLimitedStateForCTCSlaveVoLTE=false,isSWRoaming=false,isMobileDataSettingEnabled=true,nwBoosterRilEnabled=false,nwBoosterSettingEnabled=false,emergencyModeActivated=false,ismmW5G=false,slotId=0,simState=LOADED,isDefaultDataSlot=true, iconSet = [I@52fa84c
03-03 15:53:00.708  6402  6402 D StatusbarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators state = MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131233584, roaming=false, typeId=2131233372, visible=true, activityId=2131233454, roamingId=0, slotId=0)
03-03 15:53:00.711  1336 11944 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
03-03 15:53:00.711  1336  7767 D Debug   : low && ship && 3rd party app crash, so skip dump
03-03 15:53:00.711  1336  7767 W ActivityManager: crash : com.visionx.vision,10688
03-03 15:53:00.711  1336  7767 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:579 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:443 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:12396 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash:12331
03-03 15:53:00.712  1336  7767 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.visionx.vision/.VisionClassStub
03-03 15:53:00.713  1336  7767 V WindowManager: Prepare app transition: transit=TRANSIT_CRASHING_ACTIVITY_CLOSE mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_UNSET alwaysKeepCurrent=false displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5809 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.finishTopCrashedActivityLocked:2733 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.finishTopCrashedActivities:2654 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService$LocalService.finishTopCrashedActivities:8921
03-03 15:53:00.714  1336  7767 D InputDispatcher: Focused application set to (0): 13504fa
03-03 15:53:00.714  1336  7767 V WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{e4f667a u0 com.visionx.vision/com.visionx.vision.VisionClassStub} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:567 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6311 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setFocusedApp:6775 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setResumedActivityUncheckLocked:6725
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  7767 D StatusBarManagerService: notifyRequestedSystemKey recent=false home=false
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  7767 D GameManagerService: TaskStackListener.onTaskFocusChanged(), taskId=14280, focused=true
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  1882 D GameManagerService: onLooperPrepared(), msg: MSG_TASK_FOCUSED, focusedComponent: ComponentInfo{com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity}
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  1882 D GameManagerService: handleTaskFocused().
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  1882 D GameManagerService: sendFocusOutConditionally() - mPrevNotiPackage: (unknown)
03-03 15:53:00.715  1336  1882 D GameManagerService:   handleTaskFocused(), pkgName: com.sec.android.app.launcher, clsName: com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity, userID:0
03-03 15:53:00.716  1336  7767 V WindowManager: Prepare app transition: transit=TRANSIT_TASK_CLOSE mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_CRASHING_ACTIVITY_CLOSE alwaysKeepCurrent=false displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5809 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:5803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.finishIfPossible:3181 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.finishIfPossible:3053 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.finishTopCrashedActivityLocked:2735
03-03 15:53:00.716  1336  7767 D WindowManager: isScreenshotDisabledLocked - win: Window{5575bba u0 InputMethod}
03-03 15:53:00.716  1336  7767 D WindowManager: isScreenshotDisabledLocked: userId = 0, disabled =false
03-03 15:53:00.716  1336  7767 D WindowManager: isScreenshotDisabledLocked - win: Window{e4f667a u0 com.visionx.vision/com.visionx.vision.VisionClassStub}
03-03 15:53:00.716  1336  7767 D WindowManager: isScreenshotDisabledLocked: userId = 0, disabled =false
03-03 15:53:00.720   805   805 I SurfaceFlinger: operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 53555, screenshot (com.visionx.vision/com.visionx.vision.VisionClassStub$_11740#0)
03-03 15:53:00.723   805   805 I Layer   : id=6845[0] Destroyed Screenshot Parent
```

Comment: It crashes. How does it crash? What error messages do you see? What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Since it's in Android I suggest connecting a cable and looking through logcat to see if there's exceptions in the logs or some other error.

Comment: How do I look through log if my Android connects to a cable? Are there any documents about the details?

Comment: Crash means black screen with no message.

Comment: Just google android logcat. You can look through the device printout which should show you a stack trace or error messages when you see the black screen. Paste the applicable error in the question if you don't understand it and comment here so we'll get the alert

Comment: Device printout a lot of messages through. How do I paste the error about this question?

Comment: I pasted the application errors in question.

Comment: Third line of your log:`Title must be set and non-empty`

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in the docs: https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner

There's a new syntax to getting a finger print that accepts a title for the dialog that's shown. You probably need to use that new syntax.

Comment: The docs are written in codename one maven version, but my project is not. Could I have the latest FingerprintScanner version with my current cn1 project? Or how do I convert the FingerpringScanner maven version to cn1lib for my current cn1 project?

Comment: The cn1lib should be up to date and should be updatable via Codename One Settings to the same version. Regardless I would recommend migrating the project to maven

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlmog, I'm having an android issue where the app gets crashes when using the fingerprint library. I have updated the cn1 project for fingerprint already. What could be the cause of the issue? Please advise

Comment: I commented on your new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597714/fingerprint-library-is-crashing-on-new-android-devices-even-after-upgrading-cn1)