# Fingerprint library is crashing on new android devices even after upgrading CN1 library

Tags: codenameone

I'm having issues with my app which used to work on old android devices where i'm trying to upgrade the App.I have installed the new version 15 of FingerPrintScanner from CN1 library for the project. This  issue noticeable where touch fingerprint is active on the devices. Please let me know if any thoughts

````
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(value -> {
                            username.setText(Preferences.get("username", "").trim());
                            password.setText(Preferences.get("password", "").trim());
                            appNameField.setText(Preferences.get("applicationName", "").toUpperCase().trim());
                            authorizeLogin(username, password, appNameField, lastApps);
                            revalidate();
                        }, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
                            ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Finger Print Scan Failed or Cancelled!!", 4000);
                        });```
````

Comment: Can you connect the device with logcat and provide us with the error logs/messages when it fails. You can use a github gist to host the full logs as I assume it would be too long for this forum.

Comment: ``Process: com.test.tmobile, PID: 16718
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Title must be set and non-empty
 at android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt$Builder.build(BiometricPrompt.java:633)
 at com.codename1.fingerprint.impl.f$c.run(InternalFingerprintImpl.java:10)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)``

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Here is the log and you have mentioned I need to update the syntax in another post, can you give me a snippet that can be used instead of the code that i used

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint("Use your finger print to verify", value -> {
        //Authentication Successful

        //savePassword(user, pwd);

    }, (sender, err, errCode, errMsg) -> {
        //Authentication failed
    });
```

Check this [demo](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/FingerprintAuthFt.java) for more info

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `scanFingerprint` you must give it a reason string and not a blank string. This is used as a title which is the source of the error you're getting. The user receives a prompt indicating the reason the application wants the authorization, that prompt can't be blank.